# Event handlers the event handler is not invoked on clicking the button

Tags: events, event-handling

Reasons why reason the event handler is not invoked on clicking the button

Comment: Which language? Which library? Example code? This is not a real question

Comment: I agree, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't 'wired' (linked) the eventhandler to the event ?